# eslint force one line operations/wasted variables?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there any configuration parameters for the eslint to prevent useless variables like the following?

```js
divideByTwo = (input) -> {
    const uselessVar = input/2
    return uselessVar
}
```

versus:

```js
divideByTwo = (input) -> {
    return input/2
}
```

I understand it would be complicated for the linter to find all situations based on how different functions and methods would return.

Comment: I have searched https://eslint.org/docs/rules/ for the term `variable` and could not find any rule like that. I could not find anything like that on https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html either. My best guess is that it's not possible.

Comment: if there is not many places in your code then suggest to temporary disable the line with eslint-disable-next-line

Answer (score 2):

Try [eslint-plugin-no-useless-assign](https://github.com/erikdesjardins/eslint-plugin-no-useless-assign), it prevents useless assignment of the form:

```
var foo = bar;
return foo;
```

```
var foo;
// ...
foo = bar;
return foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See the [`prefer-immediate-return`](https://github.com/SonarSource/eslint-plugin-sonarjs/blob/master/docs/rules/prefer-immediate-return.md) by the [`eslint-plugin-sonarjs` plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/eslint-plugin-sonarjs).